# How to bind hard coded dropdownlist value into database using MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have created dropdownlist which populates countries name and value of country name is hardcoded. Now i want selected country name has to be stored in database. Can anyone help me please?  I tried below code in Get method,

```
SelectListItem item;
List<SelectListItem> CountryList = new List<SelectListItem>();
item = new SelectListItem();
item.Text = "India";
item.Value = "1";
myList.Add(item);
item = new SelectListItem();
item.Text = "Italy";
item.Value = "0";
CountryList.Add(item);
ViewBag.country = CountryList;
return View();
```

Model :

```
public class Createcountry
{
[Table("mytable", Schema = "public")]
    public class Create
    {


            [Key]
            [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int regionid { get; set; }
            public string countryname { get; set; }
}
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.countryname, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.country, "select country");
```

Comment: What does mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: It is getting populated, but selected value is not storing into database.

Comment: If your binding to a property, setting the `Selected` property is pointless (the selected option is is the value of `countryname` - the `Selected` property is ignored). In the second alternative it should be just `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.countryname, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.country, "select country");` (its already a select list so you don't need to create another one!)

Comment: How looks like your server code for saving to db?

Comment: When you post back, the value of `countryname` will be either `0` or `1` depending on whether you choose `India` or `Italy`. If its not working, show your POST method.

Comment: I written stored procedure to save selected data into database.

Comment: insert into country(countryname) values ($1)

Comment: It saves data which are populated from database, but for the hardcoded value it is not getting stored.

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("regionid", NpgsqlDbType.Integer));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("countryname", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));
                      
                        cmd.Parameters[0].Value = cg.regionid;
                        cmd.Parameters[1].Value = cg.countryname;

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: Hi, Thank you for your response, when i tried as you mentioned above, i am getting  runtime error such that "The ViewData item that has the key 'countryname' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.

Comment: Then you have not done it as I have said, or you have submitted the form and returned the view but forgotten to reassign the `ViewBag.country` property

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Please review my updated code and point out where i am doing mistake.

Comment: You need to include all the POST method. And are you still getting the error you mentioned in your previous comment?

Comment: Yes..Getting the same error

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: Please once again review my updated code.

Comment: I think you are not passing the ViewBag.country at the time of page loading right?

Comment: Read my previous comment! _you have ... returned the view but **forgotten** to reassign the ViewBag.country property_ When you return the view in the POST method, `ViewBag.country` is `null` so you get that exception! And why have you made `countryname` a string in the database when you only save an integer to it?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: Thank you so much. I got the solution

Comment: @Aravindan: Thank you so much for pointed out where i did mistake.

Comment: A few side notes. a) Use a `using` statement for the connection (as you did for the command), and delete `conn.Close();` b) You are only saving one row in a table so you do not need a transaction. c) Move all this database code into a separate service/repository layer

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: Thank you for your tips. I surely follow as you guided. Thank you once again.

Comment: May i know what is the solution ?

Comment: Sure. I just added following in post method: SelectListItem item;
List<SelectListItem> CountryList = new List<SelectListItem>();
item = new SelectListItem();
item.Text = "India";
item.Value = "1";
myList.Add(item);
item = new SelectListItem();
item.Text = "Italy";
item.Value = "0";
CountryList.Add(item);
ViewBag.country = CountryList;

Comment: In view, use the same code as Stephen suggests. you can see it in view code above.

Comment: @Aravind: Before Modelstate is valid, i added mentioned above lines.